# How to select Product's all categories from CategoryProductRelation table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 tables called Product, Category and CategoryProductRelation tables. Table names explain what they store, obviously.

I need to select Product and Product's all categories in EF. How can I do that?

[image: here is the image]

In my DataAccessLayer, I have built a very flexible library and it works with EF.

```
public List<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = null;
    using (var context = new BorselDBEntities())
    {
        query = context.Set<T>();

        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);
        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

here is the way of calling the Get function above. first parameter is the where condition, the second parameter is OrderBy which is null in this case. And the third parameter is Include, which binds related data from other tables into the object.

```
_productRepository.Get(p => p.UrlText == UrlText && p.Active == true,
                                      null,
                                      p => p.Brand,
                                      p => p.Brand.BrandDetail,
                                      p => p.Image,
                                      p => p.CategoryProductRelation.XXXXXXX,  //**********
                                      p => p.ProductDetail).FirstOrDefault();
```

I cannot include Product's categories. Can anybody show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the `Product's` categories by using LINQ `Select` extension method like below:

```
p => p.CategoryProductRelation.Select(x => x.Category)
```